# TypeScript Error - Type 'Ticket[] | undefined' is not an array type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-state, react-typescript

How do I append an item to an array of objects to a state (React) while using TS?

This is my code:

```
export type AppState = {
    tickets?: Ticket[],
}

export type Ticket = {
    id: string,
    title: string;
}

export type ApiC = {
    getTickets: (order:string, page:number) => Promise<Ticket[]>;
}

export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {

    state: AppState = {
    }


   fetchNewData = async () => {
        return await api.getTickets(this.state.currentOrder, this.state.page)
   }

    handleLoadMore = () => {

       let addData:Promise<Ticket[]> = this.fetchNewData()

        if (addData) 
            this.setState({
                tickets: [...this.state.tickets, addData]
            })
    }
```

I keep getting this error:

> Type 'Ticket[] | undefined' is not an array type.

I tried:

```
let addData:Ticket[] = this.fetchNewData()
```

too and the error I get:

> Type 'Promise<Ticket[]>' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Ticket[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more. Type 'Ticket[] |
> undefined' is not an array type.

I tried writing it in all kind of variations with no luck.

**Both pointing error in this line**:

```
  > 144 |               tickets: [...this.state.tickets, addData]
        |                            ^
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if `this.state.tickets` *is* undefined? The compiler's telling you the correct thing: right now, your code doesn't work in that situation.

Comment: hmmm if it's undefined - so i want to populate it with new data fetched by the api request.. i guess. in which part of the process do i do that and how? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Well, where are you currently relying on it being an array? You need to make sure it *is* by then, or handle it not being. Should it *ever* really be undefined? Also you need to handle your promises correctly; as the compiler's telling you, you can't just unilaterally decide that a function return a promise of a value will return the value itself instead.

Comment: `if (this.state.tickets) {...}` ? im not sure i understand what you said about the promise thing @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems in your code, you can fix those:

1. Remove the optional from state and initialize it with empty array

```
export type AppState = {
  tickets: Ticket[] // remove the ?
  // ...
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    tickets: [],
    // ...
  }
}
```

2. Assuming `addData` is array of `Ticket`, you need to make `handleLoadMore` function `async` to use `await` on `this.fetchNewData` to get the data returned by it:

```
handleLoadMore = async () => {
  let addData = await this.fetchNewData()

  if (addData)
    this.setState({
      tickets: [...this.state.tickets, ...addData],
    })
    // Or
    this.setState({
      tickets: this.state.tickets.concat(addData),
    })
}
```

Comment: adding the async await worked, why do I need it here? (thanks for the answer)

Comment: I think `api.getTickets` uses `axios` and returns `Promise`, so you can drop async/await from there. I mean, you can remove `async` - `await` from `fetchNewData`. Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/49938266/2873538

Answer (score 0):

You should destructure `adddata` as well.

```
tickets: [...this.state.tickets, ...addData]
```

Comment: Destructure how?

Comment: Please refer my snippet -  ```tickets: [...this.state.tickets, ...addData]```

Comment: `Type 'Promise<Ticket[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Ticket[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more. Type 'Ticket[] | undefined' is not an array type.`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem the OP asked about (but likely does solve one of the problems they'll see after they've fixed this one).

Comment: hi @jonrsharpe so what's the answer for this?

Comment: @W.Doch same as [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66457738/3001761) your array was possibly undefined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I ditched that thing I was working on after not getting any replies that day and let it be. only now I understand what was the problem back then and now.

Comment: the only thing I don't get is why does it need to have the async await too.